# Java Infra-red devices

Tags: java, windows, infrared

I want to write a Java App that can communicate with an Infra-red device. I have a USB infra-red reader that I want to use. Are there any Java Libraries that I can use to make this happen... Ideally I want the program to work on windows and macOS X. Anyone have any sample code or anything they can do to point me in the right direction, I have never worked on such a project but I need to figure it out...

Comment: Anyone have any new thoughts on this matter? Another thing that would be helpful is if there is an application out there that can intercept communication of an IR and the computer for Windows XP. I have a working driver that I want to figure out the communication protocol on so I could write my own driver.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is something:

- http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Jean_Tourrilhes/IrDA/Java.html
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/jir/files/

But everything is outdated and has low chances of running on Win or MacOSX.